# What is the number of all the possible passwords when someone say(verbally) password is 12345678.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

If someone say(verbally) his/her password is 12345678. Some example possible password are

"12345678" or "Onetwothreefourfivesixseveneight" Or "1twothreefourfivesixseveneight", "1twothreefourfivesixseven8" ...

Letters can be upper and lower case both. 
So what is the number of total possible passwords or what can be upper bound for the number of such passwords.

Some smaller cases

If they say it's "1" : 9

Then we have One, ONe, ONE, ... 8 possibilities and 1

so there are 9 passwords.

If they say it's "12": 82

then we have 8*8 only for digits case.. =64

then 12 = 1

mixed are :  one2, One2 ... 8  possibilities. + 1two, 1Two .8 possibilities = 16
should be 64+2+16 = 82

We can discount far-fetched interpretations such as "444" for "three four", since this is ungrammatical.

Comment: This is too vague, which possibilities do you take as 'correct' and which not?

Comment: Seems you are trying to bruteforce into someone's account. Well I think the numbers finite, but cases are way too many for anyone to answer.

Comment: The rules aren't specified.  Could I read this as $234(678)^5$ (as one $234$ five $678's$)?   The english language isn't mathematically precise.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You're more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. You should at least work out the cases "12" , "123" and "1234".

Comment: I am not brute forcing anyone's account.. it was just a joke question that one of my friend posted, I just got curious what is the number actually.

Comment: @lulu yes you can. If someone says it is mostly vague, It would be nice for me to even know a rough estimate or upper bound.

Comment: What about "won", "to", "too", "for", "ate", and so on?

Comment: Also, in the English language, "444" would never be described as "three four", but rather "three four**s**" (or "triple four").

Comment: @Théophile we can ignore these let's just say it is pronunciation is clear enough that he only spoke numbers.

Comment: For "one two" there are 81 possibilities, 64+1+16, not 64+2+16. You can get this more easily as 9*9, 9 possibilities for the one, times 9 for the two. Simply multiply the possibilities for each separate digit to get the total.

Comment: @Théophile yeah you are right that means we canbring this number bit down. It was just a joke question that I was curious about .. but I think It's too vague.. I should delete it.

Comment: You've left out a number of ways to say "one" How about "twoMinusOne", "2 - 1", "three-2", "$\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta$" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each digit, you have either the digit itself, or the corresponding word. Each letter of the word can be upper or lower case, so in total there are $1 + 2^l$ possibilities for a given digit, where $l$ is the number of letters in the word.

Thus, the number of possibilities for $123456789$ is
$$(1+2^3)(1+2^3)(1+2^5)\cdots(1+2^4) = 128,711,132,649.$$

I have discounted far-fetched interpretations such as "444" for "three four", since this is ungrammatical. The one exception would be "2" for "one two", as the singular here is grammatical.

Comment: I am not getting same number while calculating as this formula.

Comment: I was calculating for 8 only .. your calculation is correct.

Comment: Oh, sorry, indeed you asked for 12345678 while this is 123456789. In any case, I hope the point is clear.